# Nested Data Binding using MVVM in WPF not working

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am not able to figure out why my third Nested DataBinding in WPF is not working. I am using Entity Framework and Sql Server 2012 and following are my entities.  An Application can have more than one accounts.  There is an Accounts Table and an Applications Table.

**ENTITIES**
1. Applications
2. Accounts

**VIEWMODELS**
1. ApplicationListViewModel
2. ApplicationViewModel
3. AccountListViewModel
4. AccountViewModel

In my usercontrol I am trying to do following:
1. Use combobox to select an application using ApplicationListViewModel (**Working**)
2. Upon selected application display all accounts in datagrid (**Working**)
3. Upon selected account display details information about a particular account.(**Does not show details of the selected account**)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ApplicationListViewModel x:Key="AppList" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppList}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <GroupBox Header="View all">
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- All Applications List -->
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cbxApplicationList"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ApplicationList}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedApplication, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

                    <!-- Selected Application Accounts -->
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dtgAccounts" Height="Auto" Width="auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              DataContext="{Binding SelectedApplication.AccountLVM}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AccountList}" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
            <GroupBox x:Name="grpBoxAccountDetails" Header="New Account" >
                <!-- Selected Account Details -->
                <!-- DataContext binding does not appear to work -->
                <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedApplication.AccountLVM.SelectedAccount}"  >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            ...
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblApplication" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >Application</TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxApplication" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppList}}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationList}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedApplication.AccountLVM.SelectedAccount.ApplicationId}">
                        </ComboBox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >Title</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="200" 
                                Text="{Binding Title}" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding AddAccount}">Add</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

ApplicationListViewModel

```
class ApplicationListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
         myEntities context = new myEntities();
        private static ApplicationListViewModel instance = null;

        private ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> _ApplicationList = null;

        public ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> ApplicationList
        {
            get 
            {
                return GetApplications(); 
            }
            set {
                _ApplicationList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ApplicationList");
            }
        }

        //public ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> Cu
        private ApplicationViewModel selectedApplication = null;

        public  ApplicationViewModel SelectedApplication
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedApplication;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedApplication = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedApplication");
            }
        }


        //private ICommand showAddCommand;

        public ApplicationListViewModel()
        {
            this._ApplicationList = GetApplications();
        }

        internal ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> GetApplications()
        {
            if (_ApplicationList == null)
                _ApplicationList = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel>();
            _ApplicationList.Clear();
            foreach (Application item in context.Applications)
            {
                ApplicationViewModel a = new ApplicationViewModel(item);
                _ApplicationList.Add(a);
            }
            return _ApplicationList;
        }

        public static ApplicationListViewModel Instance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ApplicationListViewModel();
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

ApplicationViewModel

```
class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private myEntities context = new myEntities();
        private ApplicationViewModel originalValue;

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {

        }
        public ApplicationViewModel(Application acc)
        {
            //Initialize property values
            this.originalValue = (ApplicationViewModel)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
        public ApplicationListViewModel Container
        {
            get { return ApplicationListViewModel.Instance(); }
        }

        private AccountListViewModel _AccountLVM = null;

        public AccountListViewModel AccountLVM
        {
            get
            {
                return GetAccounts(); 
            }
            set
            {
                _AccountLVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AccountLVM");
            }
        }
        internal AccountListViewModel GetAccounts()
        {
            _AccountLVM = new AccountListViewModel();
            _AccountLVM.AccountList.Clear();
            foreach (Account i in context.Accounts.Where(x=> x.ApplicationId == this.Id))
            {
               AccountViewModel account = new AccountViewModel(i);
                account.Application = this;
                _AccountLVM.AccountList.Add(account);
            }
            return _AccountLVM;
        }


    }
```

AccountListViewModel

```
class AccountListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        myEntities context = new myEntities();
        private static AccountListViewModel instance = null;

        private ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> _accountList = null;

        public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> AccountList
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_accountList != null)
                    return _accountList;
                else
                    return GetAccounts(); 
            }
            set {
                _accountList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AccountList");
            }
        }
        private AccountViewModel selectedAccount = null;

        public  AccountViewModel SelectedAccount
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedAccount;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedAccount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAccount");
            }
        }
        public AccountListViewModel()
        {
            this._accountList = GetAccounts();
        }

        internal ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> GetAccounts()
        {
            if (_accountList == null)
                _accountList = new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>();
            _accountList.Clear();
            foreach (Account item in context.Accounts)
            {
                AccountViewModel a = new AccountViewModel(item);
                _accountList.Add(a);
            }
            return _accountList;
        }

        public static AccountListViewModel Instance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new AccountListViewModel();
            return instance;
        }
}
```

AccountViewModel. I am eliminating all other initialization logic aside in viewmodel for simplicity.

```
class AccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private myEntites context = new myEntities();
        private AccountViewModel originalValue;

        public AccountViewModel()
        {

        }
        public AccountViewModel(Account acc)
        {
           //Assign property values.
            this.originalValue = (AccountViewModel)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
        public AccountListViewModel Container
        {
            get { return AccountListViewModel.Instance(); }
        }
        public ApplicationViewModel Application
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Edit1:
When I data bind to view the details of the SelectedAccount with textbox it doesn't show any text.
1. Able to databind to ApplicationListViewModel to Combobox.
2. Successfully Bind to view AccountList based upon SelectedApplication
**3. Unable to Bind to SelectedAcount in the AccountListViewModel.**

I think in the following line it doesn't show any details about the selected account. I have checked all databinding syntax. In the properties I am able to view appropriate DataContext and bind to the properties.  But it doesn't show any text. When I select each individual record in the DataGrid I am able to debug the call and select the object but somehow that object is not being shown in the textbox at the very end.

```
DataContext="{Binding SelectedApplication.AccountLVM.SelectedAccount}"
```

**Edit2:**
Based upon the suggestion in the comment below I tried snoop and was able to see the title textbox row highlighted in red color.  I am trying to change the binding Path property and datacontext but still not working. When I tried to click on the "Delve Binding Expression" it gave me unhandled exception.  I don't know what that means if as it came from Snoop.

**Edit3:**
I have taken screenshots of DataContext Property for the StackPanel for the Account Details section and the text property of the textbox.

[image]

**Solution:**
Based upon suggestions below I have made following changes to my solution and made it way more simple.  I made it unnecessarily complex.
1. AccountsViewModel
2. AccountViewModel
3. ApplicationViewModel

Now I have created properties as `SelectedApplication`, `SelectedAccount` all in just one  `AccountsViewModel`.  Removed all complex DataContext syntax and now there is just one DataContext in the xaml page.

Simplified code.

```
class AccountsViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        myEntities context = new myEntities();

        private ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> _ApplicationList = null;

        public ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> ApplicationList
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ApplicationList == null)
                {
                    GetApplications();
                }
                return _ApplicationList;
            }
            set
            {
                _ApplicationList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ApplicationList");
            }
        }
        internal ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel> GetApplications()
        {
            if (_ApplicationList == null)
                _ApplicationList = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationViewModel>();
            else
                _ApplicationList.Clear();
            foreach (Application item in context.Applications)
            {
                ApplicationViewModel a = new ApplicationViewModel(item);
                _ApplicationList.Add(a);
            }
            return _ApplicationList;
        }
        //Selected Application Property
        private ApplicationViewModel selectedApplication = null;

        public ApplicationViewModel SelectedApplication
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedApplication;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedApplication = value;
                this.GetAccounts();
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedApplication");
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> _accountList = null;

        public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> AccountList
        {
            get
            {
                if (_accountList == null)
                    GetAccounts();
                return _accountList;
            }
            set
            {
                _accountList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AccountList");
            }
        }

        //public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> Cu
        private AccountViewModel selectedAccount = null;

        public AccountViewModel SelectedAccount
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedAccount;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedAccount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAccount");
            }
        }
        internal ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> GetAccounts()
        {
            if (_accountList == null)
                _accountList = new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>();
            else
                _accountList.Clear();
            foreach (Account item in context.Accounts.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == this.SelectedApplication.Id))
            {
                AccountViewModel a = new AccountViewModel(item);
                _accountList.Add(a);
            }
            return _accountList;
        }

    }
```

**XAML Side**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:AccountsViewModel x:Key="ALVModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ALVModel}}" Margin="0,0,-390,-29">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxApplicationList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ApplicationList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedApplication, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"></ComboBox>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dtgAccounts" Height="Auto" Width="auto" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AccountList}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CreatedDate" Binding="{Binding Path=CreatedDate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastModified" Binding="{Binding Path=LastModifiedDate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedAccount}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >Title</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="200" 
                     Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I didn't understood MVVM concept properly. I tried to build everything modular and in the end I screwed it up.

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I had to rush and couldn't review before posting.  I apologize.

Comment: check your datacontext/binding at runtime with snoop

Comment: Does it have anything to do with your `AccountLVM` property always getting re-created every time the setter is called, instead of returning the stored (or set) value?

Comment: To give more info AccountLVM is actually AccountListViewModel which I created in ApplicationViewModel which filters the Accounts and re-creates the AccountList in AccountListViewModel. It re-creates on Combobox selection but doesn't get recreated upon datagrid selection changed.

Comment: @Mitul in your shown Code isn't any Property Named `Title` like your Binding `Text="{Binding Title}"` need's did you miss to show us this snippet ?

Comment: Sir I omitted all the properties to put in the question on purpose to keep the question length small.  Sorry about this.  But it is in my ViewModel.

Comment: @Mitul What does Snoop say your DataContext is for the stack panel containing the account details? Does it give you a binding error, or say it's an `AccountViewModel` object?

Comment: Delve Binding Expression does not work, as you've found out. Do what @Rachel says: snoop around. Also, if your AccountLVM property is not bound two-way, don't give it a setter. It looks fishy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related to the fact you are returning a *new* `ObservableCollection` every time you call the setter for `AccountLVM`, and you are not raising your `PropertyChange` notification, so any existing bindings do not get updated

```
public AccountListViewModel AccountLVM
{
    get
    {
        return GetAccounts(); 
    }
    set
    {
        _AccountLVM = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AccountLVM");
    }
}

internal AccountListViewModel GetAccounts()
{
    _AccountLVM = new AccountListViewModel();
    _AccountLVM.AccountList.Clear();
    foreach (Account i in context.Accounts.Where(x=> x.ApplicationId == this.Id))
    {
       AccountViewModel account = new AccountViewModel(i);
        account.Application = this;
        _AccountLVM.AccountList.Add(account);
    }
    return _AccountLVM;
}
```

I find your bindings very confusing and hard to follow, however I think whenever this gets evaluated

```
DataContext="{Binding SelectedApplication.AccountLVM.SelectedAccount}"
```

it is creating a *new* `AccountLVM`, which does not have the `SelectedAccount` property set.

You don't see the existing `DataGrid.SelectedItem` change at all because it's still bound to the *old* `AccountLVM` as no `PropertyChange` notification got raised when `_accountLVM` changed, so the binding doesn't know to update.

But some other miscellaneous related to your code:

- Don't change the private version of the property unless you also raise the PropertyChange notification for the public version of the property. This applies to both your constructors and your `GetXxxxx()` methods like `GetAccounts()`.
- Don't return a method call from your getter. Instead set the value using your method call if it's null, and return the private property afterwards.

  ```
  public AccountListViewModel AccountLVM
  {
      get
      {
          if (_accountLVM == null)
              GetAccounts(); // or _accountLVM = GetAccountLVM();

          return _accountLVM;
      }
      set { ... }
  }
  ```
- It's really confusing to have the `DataContext` set in so many controls. The `DataContext` is the data layer behind your UI, and it's easiest if your UI simply reflects the data layer, and having to go all over the place to get your data makes the data layer really hard to follow.
- If you must make a binding to something other than the current data context, try to use other binding properties to [specify a different binding `Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500436/302677) before immediately going to change the `DataContext`. Here's an example using the `ElementName` property to set the binding source:

  ```
  <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" ...
           Text="{Binding ElementName=dtgAccounts, Path=SelectedItem.Title}" />
  ```
- The `DataContext` in inherited, so you don't ever need to write `DataContext="{Binding }"`
- You may want to consider re-writing your parent ViewModel so you can setup XAML like this, without all the extra `DataContext` bindings or 3-part nested properties.

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationList}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApplication}" />

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedApplication.Accounts}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}" />

  <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedAccount}">
     ...
  </StackPanel>
  ```

If you're new to the `DataContext` or struggling to understand it, I'd recommend reading [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) on my blog to get a better understanding of what it is and how it works.

Comment: I will refactor my code and post my findings. Many thanks Rachel for suggestions and your time.

Answer (score 2):

Well one major problem with this `Binding` method is, that the value is only updated, when the last property value, in your case `SelectedAccount`, is changed. The other levels are not watched by the `BindingExpression`, so if e.g. `SelectedApplication.AccountLVM` is changed the `DataContext` will not notice a difference in `SelectedAccount` because the binding is still 'watching' on the old reference and you're modifying another reference in your VM.

So I think at the start of the application `SelectedApplication` is null and the `Binding` of the `ComboBox` doesn't notice that it changes. Hmm, I thought about another binding solution, but I couldn't found one. So I suggest, that you create an additional property for reflecting `SelectedAccount` in your `ApplicationListViewModel` class.