# wpf MvvM Command data-context issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model-binding, command-pattern

I googled all I could but could not find exactly what I was looking for. I have few issues...

This is my code structure:

My Command Class:

```
 public class BrowseCommand : ICommand 
 {
   //Code here
 }
```

Inside ViewModel:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        BrowseCommand = new BrowseCommand();
    }

    public ICommand BrowseCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
  //More Code...
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ExampleViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
Window x:Class="Ship32RcParser.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >

   <Grid>
       <Button  Content="Browse" Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}"/>
       <Button  Content="Search" Command="{Binding I_NEED_HELP_HERE}"  />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I understand that my Browse works fine because of MainWindow.xaml.cs has

```
DataContext = new ExampleViewModel();
```

However I do not like that

1. I do not want to have anything in .cs file
2. How do i have more
   than one datacontext - meaning     if I want to have command from
   different ViewModel     classes... I know its possible but its going
   to be bit ugly...

When I was searching for solutions I came across dependencies. For example I could do in my xaml file something like this

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myMvvMwpfProj.ViewModel"
```

and then use "local". However, when I tried it did not work as I expected it to work...
I also saw something like

```
xmlns:local="using:myMvvMwpfProj.Command"
```

can someone explain those too please. Does "local" give me an access to classes? If I have CommandA, CommandB, CommandC classes. Should I be able to do local:CommandA.ExecuteFoo ?

I guess the big question is how do I reference/access properties from different objects. in Xaml

thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the datacontext in your View with `<Grid DataContext = "{Binding}">`

You have 1 viewmodel per view but you can have many bound commands! I suggest you look up Josh Smiths RelayCommand as this make this so much easier! A guide is here:

Create a new class

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
            _action(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And in your ViewModel

```
    public ICommand BrowseCommand {get; set;}
    public ICommand SearchCommand {get; set;}

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        this.BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(new action<object>(MethodNameEnteredHere);
        this.SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(new action<object>(OtherMethodNameEnteredHere);
    }
```

So, your xaml would be

```
<Grid DataContext = "{Binding}">
       <Button  Content="Browse" Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}"/>
       <Button  Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"  />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: As a side note, by default the `DataContext` is inherited from the parent object, so `DataContext="{Binding}"` is just useless extra code in your XAML.

Answer (score 9):

The `DataContext` in WPF is the data layer that sites behind the UI layer. Bindings are used to query properties from the data layer for use in the UI layer.

If your UI layer is going to have two buttons (Browse and Search), then you typically want your data layer to have two commands: `BrowseCommand` and `SearchCommand`

It is possible to write a binding that queries something other than the current `DataContext` though. I actually wrote another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500436/302677) yesterday about this, which contains some examples.

The most common ways are `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`, which will
find another UI element in the VisualTree so you can use it as the binding's source, like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=SomeXAMLObjectName, 
                          Path=DataContext.BrowseCommand}" />

<Button Command="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
            Path=DataContext.BrowseCommand}" />
```

A 3rd option is to create an instance of an object in the `<XXXX.Resources>` in the XAML, and set the source to that instance using it's `x:Key`, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModelInstance" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModelInstance}, 
                          Path=BrowseCommand}">
```

You can also set the binding's `Source` property to a static object so you don't need to create an instance of the object in the `.Resources`, like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyStaticClass.BrowseCommand}}">
```

This only works for static classes though, as it won't actually create a new instance of an object for the binding.

To answer your other question, when you write

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myMvvMwpfProj.ViewModel"
```

you are telling the XAML to use "local" as a shortcut to "myMvvMwpfProj.ViewModel" (xmlns stands for [XML Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181888/302677)), so something like `local:MyStaticClass.BrowseCommand` means to bind to `myMvvMwpfProj.ViewModel.MyStaticClass.BrowseCommand`.

If you're new to WPF and MVVM, I'd actually recommend checking out a couple blog articles I wrote specifically for new WPF/MVVM users.

- [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)
- [A Simple MVVM Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)

They'll help you get a better understanding of how WPF and the MVVM pattern work.

Comment: Hi Rachel, just wondering, do you still use strings in property changed notification calls or do you use expression trees these days?

Comment: @Charleh No, I typically use Microsoft PRISM's `NotificationObject` for the base class of all objects which should raise `PropertyChanged` notifications, which allows me to raise change notifications with the actual property, not a string. It makes refactoring much easier, and eliminates the chance of typos in the property name. `RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomeProperty);`

Comment: Ah right, just wondered - the expression based properties are much better for refactoring, I did see mention of notification object in the article but I've not used PRISM (I'm currently using Caliburn.Micro which has a similar sort of property notification mechanism using expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will check out your links and btw I have not seen the "Multiple dataContext for one control - MVVM" question. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your view to use objects from various viewmodels you will have to:

1. Either have some instances in your main ViewModel for the other view models you want to use  and thus your binding will be soemthing like {Binding AlternativeViewModelInstance.NewCommand}
2. Locate the regions in your view that need bindings on a different data context and separate them into different view-viewmodel couples.